# Sort array of strings in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I have an array of strings, which might contain numbers represented as strings.

```
var data = ['BK1125', '5', '3', '2', '1', '11', '001', 'BK123', 'BK121', '4']
```

Now, I want to sort it so that final output should be

```
var data = ['001', '1', '2', '3', '4','5','11','BK121', 'BK123', 'BK1125']
```

I understand that plain sort() function will not be able to do it.
I tried to look at many answers but still didn't get the expected results.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What prevents `data.sort()` from handling this?

Comment: try this `data.sort(function(a, b){ return parseInt(a.match(/(\d+)/)[0]) < parseInt(b.match(/(\d+)/)[0])  ?  -1 :  1;})`

Comment: I got this working by using the answers in the duplicated question.